# How to increase Plone login session?

Tags: session, authentication, plone

I dont want my user have to login again everyday, I would like to increase login session to a week, for example. How can I archive that?

I’ve tried to increase cookie timeout and cookie life time in ZMI -> acl-users -> session -> properties, but it doesnt work.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're on the right path :-)

Set the `Cookie validity timeout` to 0 and the `Cookie lifetime` to 7.

Make sure you're using a plone user, no one from the zope-root (inherited user).

You can check if the settings are working by check the browser resources, hier an example in chrome:

Today ist the 20. August, the Cookie `__ac` will expire in seven days. 
[image]

Comment: You are right! The "zope-root" user is exactly my case. Tested with plone users, everything work fine